# Heroku upload and script execution limitations

Tags: php, file-upload, heroku, nginx, amazon-s3

I am using PHP 5.4.12 on NGINX (custom buildpack) on Heroku. I'm running into issues when uploading images that are 1.5MB and greater in size. This is what I'm doing:

- PHP Upload to Heroku (using iFrames and Ajax)
- Crop, Resize and Mask the photo (using Imagick command line, `convert` and `composite`) on Heroku
- Move the edited image to another server (because Heroku won't let you store things long-term unless they are git pushed to the server). Right now I'm using my test environment/server for this, but I'm sure I'll eventually move this onto S3.

Any small files go through just fine. Anything bigger than a couple megs will just hang up during (what looks like) upload time. The same exact script works just fine on a different server.

I modified by `php.ini` file on Heroku, recompiled the slug, relaunched and reset the dynos. A phpinfo() call shows the increased upload limit, however the script still fails in the same way.

I understand Heroku is supposed to have a 30 second script execution limit, however, the way I see it, PHP upload happens prior to the script beginning execution in the first place.

I was originally trying to execute the upload script from a different server, however, since I'm making an Ajax request to the upload script, I run into CORS (cross origin resource sharing) limitations, and I don't like CORS workarounds since some browsers don't obey.

Any ideas how I can allow users to upload an image greater than 1.5MB, run my cropping/masking script on the image and then store the image somewhere (Amazon S3, for example)? Perhaps someone knows of a way to upload directly to Amazon, edit the images on EC2 and then move to S3?
Thanks!

PS, looking for a Flash-free solution, as I'm trying to be mobile friendly.

Comment: How did you edit `php.ini`? I am uploading to s3, but still get the error. [see my similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796980/edit-php-ini-on-heroku). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scripts start executing *before* the file upload is complete. Carefully read Heroku documentation on limits and routing, and you'll see that the time POST body is read by *your script*, and the routers limit that and limit the minimum rate at which you can read.

Heroku recommends uploading large files *directly* to S3: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#file-uploads