# FTP file upload error in a Laravel app deployed in Heroku - Use of undefined constant FTP_BINARY

Tags: heroku, file-upload, ftp, laravel-5.4, php-7.3

Heroku's php version is 7.3. When I tried to upload any file from my app(deployed in heroku) to ftp it gives this error - **Use of undefined constant FTP_BINARY - assumed 'FTP_BINARY' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in FilesystemManager.php**. But in localhost where php version is 7, it works fine.What need to be done to solve this error? I have seen a similar question here, [PHP 7.0.5: Use of undefined constant FTP_BINARY - assumed 'FTP_BINARY'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694483/php-7-0-5-use-of-undefined-constant-ftp-binary-assumed-ftp-binary)

but the answer was applied to a windows OS and I am a little lost how to implement the solution in heroku cloud ie to turn on ftp in the php version according to the accepted answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 7.0.5: Use of undefined constant FTP\_BINARY - assumed 'FTP\_BINARY'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694483/php-7-0-5-use-of-undefined-constant-ftp-binary-assumed-ftp-binary)

Comment: I have updated my question, I already saw the solution but bit confused about implementing the solution in my scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a procfile in the root folder and add this 
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -i custom_php.ini public/

create a custom_php.ini file in the root folder (which will work as php.ini) file
and add this to that file
extension=ftp.so

1. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/problem-with-ftp-in-laravel-52-on-php-717
2. [Edit php.ini on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796980/edit-php-ini-on-heroku)